# Symfony 4 TextType required = false getting Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given

Tags: php, validation, symfony4

I have a TextType field which is set as below

**Type:**

```
        ->add('zipCode',TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('maxlength' => 10),
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => null
            )
        )
```

When the data loads from the database the field is null. I just attempt to submit the form and I get

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given.
>
> at vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:174   at
>   Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor::throwInvalidArgumentException('Argument
>   1 passed to App\Entity\Patients::setZipCode() must be of the type
>   string, null given,

I'm unsure how to fix this? I WANT the value to be null...?  Perhaps it's cause I'm not loading the initial data right on the form?

Related code below, let me know if you need something further:

**Twig:**

```
{{ form_widget(view_form.zipCode, { 'attr': {'class': 'mb-2 mb-sm-0 w-100'} }) }}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function view(Request $request)
{
    $patientId = $request->query->get('id');

    if (!empty($patientId)) {
        $search = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Patients::class)
            ->find($patientId);

        if (is_null($search))
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Invalid Patient');

        $form = $this->createForm(PatientViewType::class,$search);
    }
    else
        $form = $this->createForm(PatientViewType::class);

    dump($request);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $view = $form->getData()();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($view);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Patient record updated successfully!');
    }

    return $this->render('patient/view.html.twig', [
        'view_form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the property, setter and getter for `App\Entity\Patients` to your question to rule out anything there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I WANT the value to be null...? Perhaps it's cause I'm not loading the initial data right on the form?

According to the exception message, the method `Patients::setZipCode` does not accept null values. It would seem that the value is correctly passed as `null` to your entity, but the `Patients` class does not accept the value.

I assume the `setZipCode` signature looks somewhat like this:

```
public function setZipCode(string $zipCode): void
```

You can make it accept null values by adding a question mark:

```
public function setZipCode(?string $zipCode): void
```